# Image to the right of the title when using hmsegmentedcontrol

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using [HMSegmentedControl](https://github.com/HeshamMegid/HMSegmentedControl) and by default the images are added to the left of the title when using:

```
- (instancetype)initWithSectionImages:(NSArray *)sectionImages
                sectionSelectedImages:(NSArray *)sectionSelectedImages 
                    titlesForSections:(NSArray *)sectiontitles;
```

Is there any way to add image to the right of the title without forking the [HMSegmentedControl](https://github.com/HeshamMegid/HMSegmentedControl) code?

Answer (score 0):

sectionTitles can be an array of AttributedStrings. And those can contain image attachments. That way you can use `NSAttributedString` api to have images anywhere in the title or after it!

disclaimer: given a short look at the code

#### BUT

since trying it led to crashes, this seems not to work in all cases. I don't think there is a way but forking

Comment: Thank you for looking at it.. Even though, sectionTitles is an array.. it seems to assume an array of strings. So, when I tried that it is crashing in places where sizeWithAttributes is used etc..

Comment: at least in some places it dedicatedly checks for NSString OR NSAttributedString.